# how to prevent button to be focused by default

Tags: c, gtk2

I am using GTK+2 for GUI in C language. I have 10x10 table of buttons in my code. And When I run my code, the 1st button `(button[0][0])` is focused by default. So how can I can prevent this button to be focused by default?

**Code:**

```
table = gtk_table_new(10, 10, TRUE);

for (int row=0; row<10; row++) {
    for (int col=0; col<10; col++) {
        button[row][col] = gtk_button_new_with_label(" ");
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button[row][col]), "button-release-event", G_CALLBACK(buttonClicked), NULL);
        gtk_button_set_focus_on_click(GTK_BUTTON(button[row][col]), FALSE);
        gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), button[row][col], col, col+1, row, row+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show the window, call `gtk_widget_grab_focus()` on the widget that you want to focus instead.

If you don't want the buttons in the grid to be able to focus at all, then call `gtk_widget_set_can_focus()` on them.